# Android: Camera, onSurfaceTextureUpdated, Bitmap.getPixels - framerate drops from 30 to 3

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, camera

I have quite a horrible performance when trying to get the pixels of the Camera preview.

The image format is around 600x900.
The preview rate is quite stable 30fps on my HTC one.

As soon as I try to get the pixels of the image the framerate drops to below 5!

```
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    Bitmap bmp = mTextureView.getBitmap();
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getHeight() * bmp.getWidth()];
    bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

The performance is so slow, it's not really bearable.

Now my only 'easy' solution is to skip frames to at least keep some visual performance.
But I'd actually like to have that code perform faster.

I would appreciate any ideas and suggestions, maybe someone solved this already ?

**UPDATE**

```
getbitmap: 188.341ms
array: 122ms 
getPixels: 12.330ms
recycle: 152ms
```

It takes 190 milliseconds just to get the bitmap !! That's the problem

Comment: I made some meassurements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I digged into this for several hours.

So short answer: I found no way to avoid getBitmap() and increase performance.
The function is known to be slow, I found many similar questions and no results.

However I found another solution which is about 3 times faster and solves the problem for me.
I keep using the TextureView approach, I use it because it gives more freedom on how to display the Camera preview (for example I can display the camera live preview in a small window of my own aspect ratio without distortion)

But to work with the image data I do not use onSurefaceTextureUpdated() anymore.

I registered a callback of the cameraPreviewFrame which gives me the pixel data I need.
So no getBitmap anymore, and a lot more speed.

**Fast, new code:**

```
myCamera.setPreviewCallback(preview);

Camera.PreviewCallback preview = new Camera.PreviewCallback()
{
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
        Image img = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
    }
};
```

**Slow:**

```
private int[] surface_pixels=null;
private int surface_width=0;
private int surface_height=0;
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)
{
    int width,height;

    Bitmap bmp= mTextureView.getBitmap();
    height=barcodeBmp.getHeight();
    width=barcodeBmp.getWidth();
    if (surface_pixels == null)
    {
        surface_pixels = new int[height * width];
    } else
    {
        if ((width != surface_width) || (height != surface_height))
        {
            surface_pixels = null;
            surface_pixels = new int[height * width];
        }
    }
    if ((width != surface_width) || (height != surface_height))
    {
        surface_height = barcodeBmp.getHeight();
        surface_width = barcodeBmp.getWidth();
    }

    bmp.getPixels(surface_pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    bmp.recycle();

    Image img = new Image(width, height, "RGB4");
 }
```

I hope this helps some people with the same problem.

If someone should find a way to create a bitmap in a fast manner within onSurfaceTextureUpdated please respond with a code sample.

Comment: Hey..@John...i need your Help..Please help me......i used your above First one code..but when i put your code with my code..at that time it was showing an  Error in last Line....Image img = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");....Here  Studio gives Red line and tells Image is abstract you and can not be instantiated...then what should i do..?

Comment: and also i am developing an CustomCaemra App. i had some Problem.i also want multiple camera Preview into single Activity [Like in GridView]. Please help me How can i achive this..i already asked question but nobody gave me answer....Here is my Question Link......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview

Comment: i googled it and tried more tutorial's,libraries[grafica too].but i did not achive this type of Preview[Multiple Cmaera Preview]. i found more problem's same as my problem in Stackoverflow.but same as my Question no one gave answer's.Please see this Link i want this type of View......http://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHuj.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    if (IsBusy) {
        return;
    }
    IsBusy = true;
    DoBigWork();
    IsBusy = false;      
}
```