# How to Apply Custom Filters in a Camera [Surfaceview Preview]...?

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview

Guys i am developing Camera Application and this is my first android Application.

below i am Adding My App Screenshot for what i want.

First View :

[image]

Here , after Clicking on a Top-Right Corner Filter icon i want a below View.

Second View :

[image]

i don't know how can i get this type of a view. also how can i design this type of view into XML parts.

and i read more articles like how to Open a Multiple Surface-view Preview onto single screen but i did not get any much appreciate solution.

and Finally after selecting any of the Filter Preview i want a above Image type View.

means Selected Filter's is Preview apply onto Camera [Surfaceview Preview].
Please provide any type of Material link example.etc

guys please help me.any type of help will be appreciated..):

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800639/camera-preview-on-multiple-views-initialize-release-handling

Answer (score 1):

From the images, it's from a app called Geak Camera. Actually, I developed this app, and I used the GLSurfaceView not the surfaceview. And the app is not maintained now because I left that company. And I updated that app called "U camera".The scale animation was improved in "U camera".

Answer (score 1):

All these manipulations can be performed with OpenCV. Download their basic Android example, and you can add your logic to `onCameraFrame()` callback.